# Factorization of the symmetric function identity $E(t)=1/H(t)$ with the refined Euler characteristic polynomials of associahedra / Lagrange inversion

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, symmetric-functions

I've come across two matrix identities, flagged with daggers below, relating the two sets of [elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) and [complete homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_homogeneous_symmetric_polynomial) symmetric polynomials/functions via the two sets of refined Lah and associahedra partition polynomials (see OEIS [A130561](https://oeis.org/A130561) and [A133437](https://oeis.org/A133437)). I wonder where these identities occur in the vast literature on symmetric functions.

Define the elementary symmetric polynomials $e_n$ (functions for $m = \infty$) by

$E(t;x_1,x_2,...,x_m) = (1-x_1 t)(1-x_2 t)\cdots (1-x_m t) = 1 + e_1(x_1,...,x_m)t + e_2(x_1,...,x_m)t^2 + \cdots$

and the complete homogeneous symmetric polynomials/functions $h_n$ by

$H(t;x_1,x_2,...,x_m) = 1 / E(t;x_1,...,x_m) = 1 + h_1(x_1,...,x_m)t + h_2(x_1,...,x_m)t^2 + \cdots$.

The reciprocal relationship between $H(t)$ and $E(t)$ provides the o.g.f. for the $e_n$ in terms of the $h_n$ as illustrated in the easy-reference section below. See also OEIS [A263633](https://oeis.org/A263633), a refined Pascal triangle.

Among the numerous other relationships among the symmetric polynomials are two that involve the refined Lah partition polynomials $L_n(x)$ of [A130561](https://oeis.org/A130561) defined by the e.g.f.

$e^{L.(x)t} = e^{x tH(t)}$

with the first few being

$L_0(x) = 1$

$L_1(x) = x$

$L_2(x) =  x^2 + 2h_1x$

$L_3(x) = x^3 + 6 h_1 x^2 + 6 h_2x $

$L_4(x) = x^4 + 12 h_1 x^3 + (12 h_1^2 + 24 h_2) x^2 + 24 h_3x$

$L_5(x) = x^5 + 20 h_1 x^4 + 60 (h_1^2 + h_2) x^3 + 120 (h_1 h_2 + h_3) x^2 + 120 h_4 x)$.

The numerical coefficients of the monomial summands of $L_n(x)$ are given by

$C_L(n,k,p_1,p_2,...,p_m) = \frac{n!}{(k-(p_1+p_2+...))! p_1!p_2!...}$

with $k$ the exponent of $x$ in the monomial and $p_k$, the ex'p'onent of $h_k$; e.g., for the monomial $h_1^2x^3$ of $L_5(x)$, $C(5,3,2,0,...,0) = \frac{5!}{(3-(2))! 2!} = 60$.

The associated coefficient matrix $[L]$ is partially displayed below in the easy reference section .

Define the associahedra partition polynomials $A_n(h_1,h_2,...,h_n)$, a.k.a. the refined Euler characteristic polynomials of the associahedra (see [A133437](https://oeis.org/A133437)), with the indeterminates being the complete homogeneous symmetric polynomials $h_k$, as the compositional inverse about the origin of the formal o.g.f. $tH(t)$; i.e., $(tH(t))^{<-1>} = t + A_1(h_1)t^2 + A_2(h_1,h_2)t^2 + \cdots$ with the first few being

$A_0 = 1$

$A_1 = - h_1 $,

$A_2 =  2 h_1^2 -  h_2$,

$A_3 = -5 h_1^3 + 5 h_1h_2 -  h_3$,

$A_4 = 14 h_1^4 - 21 h_1^2 h_2 + 6  h_1 h_3 + 3 h_2^2 -   h_4$,

$A_5 = -42 h_1^5 + 84 h_2 h_1^3 - 28 h_3 h_1^2 - 28 h_2^2 h_1 + 7 h_4 h_1 + 7 h_2 h_3 - h_5$.

The numerical coefficient of the monomial in $A_n$ with exponents $p_1,p_2,...$, whose sum of exponents is $s=p_1+p_2+...+p_n$, is

$C_A(n,s,p_1,...,p_n) = (-1)^{s} \frac{1}{n+1}\frac{(n+s)!}{n!p_1!p_2!p_3!\cdots}.$

Form the single column matrices. i.e., vectors,

$[NE] = (1,e_1(h_1),2!e_2(h_1,h_2),3!e_3(h_1,h_2,h_3),...)^T$

$[NA] = (1,A_1(h_1),2!A_2(h_1,h_2),3!A_3(h_1,h_2,h_3),...)^T$

Then the matrix identity

$$(\dagger)$$

$$[NE] = [L][NA]$$

holds.

Form the diagonal normalization matrices

$[DIF] = diag(0!,1!,1/2!,1/3!,...)$

and

$[DF] = diag(0!,1!,2!,3!,...)$

and the two column vectors

$[E] = (1,e_1(h_1),e_2(h_1,h_2),e_3(h_1,h_2,h_3),...)^T$

and

$[A]=(1,A_1(h_1),A_2(h_1,h_2),...)^T.$

Then the $(\dagger)$ identity implies

$$(\dagger\dagger)$$

$$[E] = [DIF][L][DF][A] = [R][A]$$

with the conjugation

$[R] = [DIF][L][DF] = [DF]^{-1}[L][DF] $

containing the coefficients of the polynomials $R_n(x;h_1,...,h_n)$ with the o.g.f.

$\frac{1}{ 1 -x tH(t)} = \frac{1}{1 - xt( 1 + h_1  t + h_2  t^2 + h_3  t^3 +  ... )} = 1 + R_1t + R_2t^2 + \cdots$

with the first few being

$R_0 = 1$

$R_1(x) = x$

$R_2(x) = x^2 + h_1 x$

$R_3(x) = x^ 3 + 2 h_1 x^2 + h_2 x$

$R_4(x) = x^4 + 3 h_1 x^3 + (h_1^2 + 2 h_2) x^2 + h_3  x$

$R_5(x) = x^5 + 4 h_1 x^4 + 3 (h_1^2  + h_2) x^3 +  2(h_1h_2 + h_3) x^2  + h_4 x$

with the numerical coefficients of the monomials given by

$C_R(k,p) = \frac{k!}{(k-(p_1+p_2+\cdots)))!p_1!p_2! \cdots} = \frac{k!}{(k-s))!p_1!p_2!\cdots}$

where $k$ is the exponent of $x$; $p_j$, the exponent of $h_j$; and $s$ is the sum of the exponents of the $h_j$'s. Note for $R_n$ that for each monomial $n = k + 1 \cdot p_1 + 2 \cdot p_2 + 3\cdot p_3 + \cdots$. These same coefficients occur in OEIS [A263633](https://oeis.org/A263633), a refined Pascal triangle.

([A related M_O question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461532/matrix-transform-of-the-bivariate-narayana-polynomials-into-the-arithmetic-and-g) involves $e_n(a,b)$ and $h_n(a,b)$ and the Narayana polynomials, the simple h-polynomials of the associahedra.)

The two matrix identities are equivalent to the umbral compositional identities $NE_n = L_n(NA.)$ and $E_n = R_n(A.)$. Such identities are easily derived using the umbral calculus of Sheffer polynomial sequences and are presented in several old notes of mine, e.g., "[Composition, Conjugation, and the Umbral Calculus II:
Partition polynomials](https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2021/11/21/composition-conjugation-and-the-umbral-calculus-ii-partition-polynomials/)" with application to the Bernoulli numbers and polynomials in "[Composition, Conjugation, and the Umbral Calculus–Part I](https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2021/11/20/composition-conjugation-and-the-umbral-calculus-part-i/)".

---

---

For **easy reference**, the first few rows of the matrices are

$[NE] = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
-h_1\\ 
2!(h_1^2 - h_2)\\ 
3!(-h_1^3 + 2 h_2 h_1 - h_3)\\ 
4!(h_1^4 - 3 h_2 h_1^2 + 2 h_3 h_1 + h_2^2 - h_4)\\ 
5!(-h_1^5 + 4 h_2 h_1^3 - 3 h_3 h_1^2 - 3 h_2^2 h_1 + 2 h_4 h_1 + 2 h_2 h_3 - h_5)
\end{bmatrix}$

$[L] = \begin{bmatrix}
 1&  &  &  &  & \\ 
 0&  1&  &  &  & \\ 
 0& 2h_1 &  1&  &  & \\ 
 0& 6h_2 &  6h_1&  1&  & \\ 
 0&  24h_3&  12 h_1^2 + 24 h_2&  12 h_1&  1& \\ 
 0&  120h_4&  120 (h_1 h_2 + h_3)&  60 (h_1^2 + h_2)&  20 h_1&1 
\end{bmatrix}$

$[NA] =\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
- h_1\\ 
2!(2 h_1^2 -  h_2)\\ 
3!(-5 h_1^3 + 5 h_1h_2 -  h_3)\\ 
4!(14 h_1^4 - 21 h_1^2 h_2 + 6  h_1 h_3 + 3 h_2^2 -   h_4)\\ 
5!(-42 h_1^5 + 84 h_2 h_1^3 - 28 h_3 h_1^2 - 28 h_2^2 h_1 + 7 h_4 h_1 + 7 h_2 h_3 - h_5)
\end{bmatrix} $

$[E] = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
-h_1\\ 
h_1^2 - h_2\\ 
-h_1^3 + 2 h_2 h_1 - h_3\\ 
h_1^4 - 3 h_2 h_1^2 + 2 h_3 h_1 + h_2^2 - h_4\\ 
-h_1^5 + 4 h_2 h_1^3 - 3 h_3 h_1^2 - 3 h_2^2 h_1 + 2 h_4 h_1 + 2 h_2 h_3 - h_5
\end{bmatrix}$

Again, in a different format,

$e_0 = 1$

$e_1 = - h_1$

$e_2 = h_1^2 - h_2$

$e_3 = -h_1^3 + 2 h_2 h_1 - h_3$

$e_4 =  h_1^4 - 3 h_2 h_1^2 + 2 h_3 h_1 + h_2^2 - h_4$

$e_5 = -h_1^5 + 4 h_2 h_1^3 - 3 h_3 h_1^2 - 3 h_2^2 h_1 + 2 h_4 h_1 + 2 h_2 h_3 - h_5$

with the numerical coefficients of the monomials of $e_n$ given by

$C_E(s,p_1,p_2,...) =(-1)^s \frac{s!}{p_1!p_2!p_3!\cdots}$

where $s = p_1+p_2+p_3+\cdots$, i.e., the sum of the exponents $p_k$ of the $h_k$.

$[R] = \begin{bmatrix}
 1&  &  &  &  & \\ 
 0&  1&  &  &  & \\ 
 0& h_1 &  1&  &  & \\ 
 0&  h_2&  2h_1&  1&  & \\ 
 0&  h_3&  h_1^2 + 2 h_2&  3h_1&  1& \\ 
 0&  h_4& 2(h_1h_2 + h_3) &  3 (h_1^2  + h_2)&  4h_1& 1
\end{bmatrix} $

$[A] = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
- h_1\\ 
2 h_1^2 -  h_2\\ 
-5 h_1^3 + 5 h_1h_2 -  h_3\\ 
14 h_1^4 - 21 h_1^2 h_2 + 6  h_1 h_3 + 3 h_2^2 -   h_4\\ 
-42 h_1^5 + 84 h_2 h_1^3 - 28 h_3 h_1^2 - 28 h_2^2 h_1 + 7 h_4 h_1 + 7 h_2 h_3 - h_5
\end{bmatrix}$